# Reflection - SetValue from deep context

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, .net-5, system.text.json

I am facing an issue, surely due to my lack of knowledge in the reflection process, while trying to set a "complex" class hierarchy based on Json files.

Here are my main model :

```
public class Names
{
    public Weapons Weapons { get; set; }
    public Armors Armors { get; set; }
    public Utilities Utilities { get; set; }
    public Names()
    {
        Weapons = new Weapons();
        Armors = new Armors();
        Utilities = new Utilities();
    }
}
```

Each of them having a list of sub-model like this:

```
public class Weapons
{
    public BattleAxe BattleAxe { get; set; } = new BattleAxe();
    public Bomb_Missile Bomb_Missile { get; set; } = new Bomb_Missile();
    // etc... Around 20 to 25
}
```

And finally the ended model which is the exact equivalent of each json files but may have very different properties :

```
public class BattleAxe
{
    public string[] Normal { get; set; } = new string[0];
    public string[] DescriptiveAdjective { get; set; } = new string[0];
    public string[] Material { get; set; } = new string[0];
    public string[] Type { get; set; } = new string[0];
    public string[] Title { get; set; } = new string[0];
    public string[] Of { get; set; } = new string[0];
    public string[] NormalForTitle { get; set; } = new string[0];
}
```

Since the MS Json deserializer does not support the conversion to a $type as Newtonsoft before, I tried to populate the values using reflection too like this (I've removed all the null-check for code readability) :

```
public static void Load()
{
    Names = new Names();
    foreach (var category in Names.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (category is not null && !(category.GetGetMethod()?.IsStatic ?? false))
        {
            var categoryType = category.PropertyType;
            foreach (var item in category.PropertyType.GetProperties())
            {
                var itemType = item.PropertyType;
                var subTypeData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, JsonElement>>(File.ReadAllText($"./Assets/Names/{categoryType.Name}/{itemType.Name}.json"));
                var concreteObj = Activator.CreateInstance(itemType);
                foreach (var key in subTypeData.Keys)
                {
                    if (itemType.GetProperty(key) is not null && concreteObj is not null)
                    {
                        var prop = concreteObj.GetType().GetProperty(key);
                        var convertedValue = ConvertJsonType(subTypeData[key], subTypeData[key].ValueKind, out var isReferenceType);
                        // It fails here
                        prop.SetValue(
                            isReferenceType ? convertedValue : null,
                            !isReferenceType ? convertedValue : null
                        );
                    }
                }
                item.SetValue(concreteObj, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So it fails at the `prop.SetValue(...)` of the deepest object in the hierarchy with a different error depending on the type of value to set.
If it is a reference, it throws a `System.Reflection.TargetException : 'Object does not match target type' Exception`
And if it is value, it throw a `System.Reflection.TargetException : 'Non-static method requires a target.'`
Knowing that I do not have problems around the deserialization as shown here, only the fact that I use a dynamic type (and my instinct tells me it is actually the problem...)
[image: debug]

I do not add the `ConvertJsonType(...)` body as it is functional and really simple

I am more interested in the 'why' than the 'how' so if you can explain me the 'theory' behind the problem, that would help quite a lot :)

Thank you!

PS: I know I can simplify the things in a more readable/performant way but I must achieve it with reflection for personal learning :)
Same for the System.Text.Json namespace, I do not intend to switch back to Newtonsoft for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue?view=net-5.0) state `TargetException` is thrown when:

> The type of `obj` does not match the target type, or a property is an instance property but `obj` is `null`.

Passing `null` for `obj` in `SetValue` is valid when you are trying to set value for static property, not an instance one. Property type being a reference one has nothing to do with property being instance or static one so your call should look something like:

```
prop.SetValue(concreteObj, convertedValue);
```

Also your `item.SetValue(concreteObj, null);` does not look right cause `concreteObj` should be second argument in this call. Something like this:

```
item.SetValue(Names, concreteObj);
```

Also if you want only instance properties you can provide `BindingFlags` to get only instance properties:

```
foreach (var category in Names.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
```

Also I would say that `category is not null` check is redundant so in pair with providing `BindingFlags` you should remove the `if` completely.

Comment: It was indeed a misunderstood regarding the SetValue function, dummy mistake sorry :/
Thank you for the BindingFlags use too, that's more elegant.
There was a problem with the `item.SetValue(concreteObj, null);` as you said but I needed to set the category class instead of the Names one. As I didnt have any reference to it yet, I had to use the GetValue (yet another reflection call...) on Names.

Thank you for the exaplanation and tips :)

Answer (score 2):

When calling `SetValue(instance, value)` you should pass the object which property should be set.

It's a wild guess, but you could try this:

```
prop.SetValue(concreteObj,
              !isReferenceType ? convertedValue : null);
```

Because you want to fill the properties of `concreteObj`, not the value it self.

If you look at the object `prop` it was a return value of `concreteObj.GetType().GetProperty(key);`. If you look at it close, The `GetProperty` is a method from `Type` which isn't bound to any instance. So that's why you need to pass the instance of the object as the first parameter.

---

I mean this in a positive way: The `itemType.GetProperty(key)` is called every iteration, it will be the same value each iteration, you could bring it before the loop.

Comment: Kind of the same answer as Guru, so it was indeed a wrong use of SetValue. I just find his explanation more appealing to me but thats just a question of style, both was the correct solution, thank you :)

About your `itemType.GetProperty(key)` comment, How would I be able to to get it before looping as its purpose it to check if the current Key from my json object that I am using is correctly present in my model class ? I know its costly but I dont have any simple idea to reduce its use

Comment: Only my answer was before his. At least you found it.